# How to enable x-ray tracing for all methods being invoked in the API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-xray

I need to debug which method is consuming more time in the lambda invocation, but to enable tracing for any method, we need add @xray_recorder.capture  decorator like below.

```py
from aws_xray_sdk.core import xray_recorder

@xray_recorder.capture("my_method")
def my_method():
    pass
```

How can we dynamically add or any other method to enable tracing for all the methods ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the middleware provided by xray_sdk to do this, you can also configure which modules to monitor, and which to ignore using the `XRAY_RECORDER` setting.

For more info go through the [xray_sdk_middleware](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-python/blob/master/README.md#add-django-middleware) docs in GitHub.